# AssertionError in method of python class

Tags: python, pandas, class, assertion

I am making a python script that uses PyQt5 to display a GUI. Somewhere in the code i want to get all the unique values from a excel file the user has put in. There seems to be a problem in this function with asserting thr file path and a AssertionError follows.

I think it has to do with the globality of the variables used.

Here is my code, the problem is in the class 'CalculationsThread'.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar, QLabel, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QGridLayout, QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject, QEvent
from PIL import Image, ImageQt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QColor, QStandardItem
import xlsxwriter
    
    color = '#FFFFFF'
    colorbg = '#BBBBBB'
    nr_weken = 40
    
    
    class LoadingBarThread(QThread):
        loading_completed = pyqtSignal()
    
        def __init__(self, seconds):
            super().__init__()
            self.seconds = seconds
            
    
        def run(self, seconds):
            app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        
            # Maak het hoofdvenster
            venster = QMainWindow()
            venster.setWindowTitle("Laadbalk")
        
            # Maak het centrale widget
            centraal_widget = QWidget()
            venster.setCentralWidget(centraal_widget)
        
            # Maak de lay-outmanager
            layout = QVBoxLayout()
            centraal_widget.setLayout(layout)
        
            # Maak het label voor de uitlegtekst
            uitleg_label = QLabel()
            uitleg_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
            uitleg_label.setText("Met behulp van de door u aangevoerde bestanden worden een aantal berekeningen uitgevoerd.\nDit kan even duren, bedankt voor uw geduld!")
            layout.addWidget(uitleg_label)
        
            # Maak de laadbalk
            laadbalk = QProgressBar()
            layout.addWidget(laadbalk)
        
            # Maak het label voor de voortgangstekst
            label = QLabel()
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
            layout.addWidget(label)
        
            # Bepaal het totale aantal updates
            totaal_updates = 100
        
            # Houd bij hoeveel updates er al zijn uitgevoerd
            huidige_update = 0
        
            # Update de voortgang van de laadbalk
            def update_laadbalk():
                nonlocal huidige_update
                huidige_update += 1
        
                if huidige_update >= totaal_updates:
                    timer.stop()
                    venster.close()
                else:
                    laadbalk.setValue(huidige_update)
                    label.setText(f"Bezig met laden... {huidige_update}%")
        
            # Bepaal het aantal milliseconden per update van de laadbalk
            milliseconden_per_update = int((self.seconds * 1000) / totaal_updates)
        
            # Maak een timer voor de updates van de laadbalk
            timer = QTimer()
            timer.timeout.connect(update_laadbalk)
        
            # Start de timer voor de eerste update van de laadbalk
            timer.start(milliseconden_per_update)
        
            # Centreren van het venster op het scherm
            venster.move(QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center() - venster.rect().center())
        
            # Stel de juiste venstergrootte in op basis van de inhoud
            venster.setMinimumSize(venster.sizeHint())
        
            # Toon het venster
            venster.show()
        
            # Start de event loop
            sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    
    class CalculationsThread(QThread, XeduleTool):
        calculations_completed = pyqtSignal(list)
    
        def __init__(self, dfdatafunc, dfeisenfunc, sheetnamedatafunc, sheetnameisenfunc, filepathdatafunc, filepatheisenfunc):
            super().__init__()
            self.dfdata = dfdatafunc
            self.dfeisen = dfeisenfunc
            self.sheetnamedata = sheetnamedatafunc
            self.sheetnameisen = sheetnameisenfunc
            self.filepathdata = filepathdatafunc
            self.filepatheisen = filepatheisenfunc
            global sheetnamedata, sheetnameisen, filepathdata, filepatheisen
            self.run2(self.dfdata, self.dfeisen, self.sheetnamedata, self.sheetnameisen, self.filepathdata, self.filepatheisen)
            
        def extract_unique_values(self, file_path, sheet_name, column_header):
            print('unique gestart')
            df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)
            column_number = df.columns.get_loc(column_header) + 1  # Get the column number
            values = df.iloc[:, column_number - 1].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().str.strip()
            unique_values = values.unique().tolist()
            if column_header in unique_values:  
                unique_values.remove(column_header)
            return unique_values
    
        def run2(self, dfdata, dfeisen, sheetnamedata, sheetnameisen, filepathdata, filepatheisen):
            # print('rekenen gestart')
            self.unique_teams = self.extract_unique_values(filepathdata, sheetnamedata, 'Team')
            # dan nu het stuk waarin gekeken wordt of het rooster zich aan de eisen houdt.
            
            self.unique_facilities = self.extract_unique_values(filepathdata, sheetnamedata, 'Gegeven in faciliteiten')
            self.unique_classes = self.extract_unique_values(filepathdata, sheetnamedata, 'Gevolgd door groepen')
            self.unique_opmerkingen = self.extract_unique_values(filepathdata, sheetnamedata, 'Opmerking')
            self.unique_vakcodes = self.extract_unique_values(filepathdata, sheetnamedata, 'Vakcode')
            self.number_unique_classes = len(self.unique_classes)
            LokalenPraktijk = []
            LokalenTheorie = []
            LokalenVermijden = []   
            LokalenOnbekend = []
            conditions = {
                'P': ('LokalenPraktijk', ['_P_', 'P_', '_P','P']),
                'V': ('LokalenVermijden', ['_V_', 'V_', '_V']),
                'T': ('LokalenTheorie', ['_T_', 'T_', '_T', 'T']),
                'BIC': ('LokalenOnbekend', ['BIC']),
                'C': ('LokalenTheorie', ['_C_', 'C_', '_C', 'C']),
                'PJ': ('LokalenTheorie', ['_PJ_', 'PJ_', '_PJ'])
            }
            
            for item in self.unique_facilities:
                added = False
                for key, value in conditions.items():
                    list_name, underscore_conditions = value
                    if any(condition in item for condition in underscore_conditions):
                    #if key in item and any(condition in item for condition in underscore_conditions):
                        if item not in LokalenTheorie and item not in LokalenPraktijk and item not in LokalenVermijden:
                            globals()[list_name].append(item)  # Voeg item toe aan de juiste lijst
                            added = True
                            break
            
                if not added:
                    LokalenOnbekend.append(item)  # Voeg item toe aan LokalenOnbekend als het niet aan andere lijsten is toegevoegd
                    
            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Dan nu kijken welke opleiding hoeveel uur per soort lokaal gebruikt.
            # Opslaan gebeurt in dataframe zodat die naar excel getransformeerd kan worden
            
            FacilitiesWithType = {'Praktijk': 'LokalenPraktijk',
                                  'Theorie': 'LokalenTheorie',
                                  'Onbekend': 'LokalenOnbekend'}
            
            dfREPerFacilityType = pd.DataFrame(int(0), index=self.unique_teams, columns=['Praktijk', 'Theorie', 'Onbekend'])
            dfToegestaanPerFacilityType = pd.DataFrame(int(0), index=self.unique_teams, columns=['Praktijk', 'Theorie'])
            
            # Loop over each row in dfdata, excluding the header row
            for i in range(0, len(dfdata)):
                i = int(i)
                team = dfdata.iloc[i]['Team']
                gegeven_faciliteiten = dfdata.iloc[i]['Gegeven in faciliteiten']
                duur_re = int(dfdata.iloc[i]['Duur (RE)'])
            
                # Check if gegeven_faciliteiten is in LokalenOmit
                if gegeven_faciliteiten in LokalenVermijden:
                    continue
            
                # Split the gegeven_faciliteiten values by ', '
                faciliteiten_list = str(gegeven_faciliteiten).split(', ')
            
                # Find the corresponding row in dfREPerFacilityType using the team value
                if team in dfREPerFacilityType.index:
                    row_index = dfREPerFacilityType.index.get_loc(team)
            
                    # Check if any of the faciliteiten values match the four lists
                    for faciliteit in faciliteiten_list:
                        if faciliteit in LokalenOnbekend:
                            facility_type = 'Onbekend'
                        elif faciliteit in LokalenPraktijk:
                            facility_type = 'Praktijk'
                        elif faciliteit in LokalenTheorie:
                            facility_type = 'Theorie'
                        else:
                            continue
            
                        # Add the duur_re to the existing value in dfREPerFacilityType
                        dfREPerFacilityType.at[team, facility_type] += duur_re
            
            
            # Stuk code die de eisen uit het juiste bestand trekt.
                        
            for index, row in dfToegestaanPerFacilityType.iterrows():
                # Iterate over the columns of the current row
                for column in dfToegestaanPerFacilityType.columns:
                    # Access the cell value using the column name
                    cell_value = row[column]
                    if column == 'Theorie':
                        dfeisenrow = 'aantal RE p week toegestane theorie'
                    else:
                        dfeisenrow = 'aantal RE p week toegestane practica'
                    if index not in dfeisen.columns.values.tolist():
                        continue
                    else:
                        dfToegestaanPerFacilityType.at[index, column] = nr_weken*int(dfeisen.at[dfeisenrow, index])
                        
            dfEvaluatieTheorie = pd.DataFrame(int(0), index=self.unique_teams, columns=['Toegestaan', 'Gebruikt', 'Verschil'])
            dfEvaluatiePraktijk = pd.DataFrame(int(0), index=self.unique_teams, columns=['Toegestaan', 'Gebruikt', 'Verschil'])
            dfEvaluatieOnbekend = pd.DataFrame(int(0), index=self.unique_teams, columns=['Onbekend'])
            global dataframes_eval
            dataframes_eval = []
            # Itereer over de gegeven dataframes en vul de kolommen 'Toegestaan', 'Gebruikt' en 'Verschil'
            # met waarden op basis van overeenkomende indexwaarden uit andere dataframes
            data_frames = [(dfEvaluatieTheorie, 'Theorie'), (dfEvaluatiePraktijk, 'Praktijk'), (dfEvaluatieOnbekend, 'Onbekend')]
            
            for df, column_name in data_frames:
                for index, row in df.iterrows():
                    for column in df.columns:
                        cell_value = row[column]
                        if column == 'Toegestaan':
                            df.at[index, column] = dfToegestaanPerFacilityType.loc[index, column_name]
                        elif column == 'Gebruikt':
                            df.at[index, column] = dfREPerFacilityType.loc[index, column_name]
                        elif column == 'Verschil':
                            df.at[index, column] = df.at[index, 'Toegestaan'] - df.at[index, 'Gebruikt']
                        elif column == 'Onbekend':
                            df.at[index, column] = dfREPerFacilityType.loc[index, column_name]
                dataframes_eval.append(df)
            self.calculations_completed.emit(dataframes_eval)
            
    class DataLoader(QObject):
        global calculating_finishes, loading_finishes
        calculating_finishes = False
        loading_finishes = False
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.loading_thread = None
            self.calculations_thread = None
            self.headers = []
            self.message = ''
    
        def create_loading_bar(self, seconds):
            self.loading_thread = LoadingBarThread(seconds)
            self.loading_thread.loading_completed.connect(self.loading_completed)
            self.loading_thread.start()
    
        def perform_calculations(self, dfdata, dfeisen, sheetnamedata, sheetnameisen, filepathdata, filepatheisen):
            self.calculations_thread = CalculationsThread(dfdata, dfeisen, sheetnamedata, sheetnameisen, filepathdata, filepatheisen)
            self.calculations_thread.calculations_completed.connect(self.calculations_completed)
            self.calculations_thread.start()
    
        def run_loading_and_calculations(self, seconds, dfdata, dfeisen, sheetnamedata, sheetnameisen, filepathdata, filepatheisen):
            self.create_loading_bar(seconds)
            self.perform_calculations(dfdata, dfeisen, sheetnamedata, sheetnameisen, filepathdata, filepatheisen)
    
        def loading_completed(self):
            print("Loading bar finished.")
            # Perform any necessary post-loading completion actions here
            global loading_finishes
            loading_finishes = True
    
        def calculations_completed(self, dataframes):
            print("Calculations finished.")
            self.headers = ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3']
            self.message = 'Hier staan de waarden per soort opleiding.'
            # Process the calculated dataframes as needed
            global calculating_finishes
            calculating_finishes = True
            # self.evaluatiescherm = Evaluatiescherm(dataframes_eval)
            # self.evaluatiescherm.show()
            
            
    class XeduleTool(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.dfdata = None
            self.dfeisen = None
            self.sheetnamedata = None
            self.sheetnameisen = None
            self.filepathdata = None
            self.filepatheisen = None
            self.setWindowTitle('Xedule tool')
            self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    
            self.file_paths = []
    
            self.button_labels = ['Open het Xedule excel bestand.', 'Open hier het bestand met de eisen gedefinieerd.']
    
            self.button_text = [button_label for button_label in self.button_labels]
    
            self.font = QFont('Calibri')
    
            self.knopdata = QPushButton(self.button_text[0], self)
            self.knopdata.setFont(QFont(self.font.family(), 13))
            self.knopdata.clicked.connect(lambda: self.open_file(0))
            self.knopdata.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FFFFFF;")
            self.knopdata.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    
            self.knopeisen = QPushButton(self.button_text[1], self)
            self.knopeisen.setFont(QFont(self.font.family(), 13))
            self.knopeisen.clicked.connect(lambda: self.open_file(1))
            self.knopeisen.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FFFFFF;")
            self.knopeisen.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    
            self.filename_labels = [QLabel('', self) for _ in range(len(self.button_labels))]
            for filename_label in self.filename_labels:
                filename_label.setFont(QFont(self.font.family(), 12))
                filename_label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
                filename_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    
            self.boodschap = QLabel("In dit programma kunt u 2 bestanden inladen.\n\nEén bestand is het excel bestand wat uit Xedule geïmporteerd is,\nde ander is het bestand met de eisen.", self)
            self.boodschap.setFont(QFont(self.font.family(), 15))
            self.boodschap.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
            self.boodschap.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    
            self.btKlaar = QPushButton("Klaar", self)
            self.btKlaar.setFont(QFont(self.font.family(), 13))
            self.btKlaar.clicked.connect(self.run_data_loading_and_calculations)
            self.btKlaar.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FFFFFF;")
            self.btKlaar.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    
            self.logo_path = "C:/Users/Floris/Documents/Toegepaste wiskunde/Jaar 2 v2/Beroepsoriëntatie/Python/fontys_logo.png"  # Path to the logo image file
            self.logo_label = QLabel(self)
            self.logo_label.setPixmap(self.get_scaled_logo())
            self.logo_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
    
            self.init_ui()
            
        def init_ui(self):
            self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.knopdata, 3, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignLeft)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.knopeisen, 5, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignLeft)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.filename_labels[0], 4, 0, 1, 2, Qt.AlignLeft)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.filename_labels[1], 6, 0, 1, 2, Qt.AlignLeft)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.boodschap, 0, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignLeft)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.btKlaar, 8, 0, 1, 1, Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignBottom)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.logo_label, 8, 1, 1, 1, Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
    
            self.central_widget = QWidget()
            self.central_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)
            self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
    
            self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())
    
            self.show()
            
        def open_file(self, index):
            options = QFileDialog.Options()
            options |= QFileDialog.ReadOnly
    
            file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "", "All Files (*);;Excel Files (*.xlsx)", options=options)
            if file_path:
                self.file_paths.insert(index, file_path)
                filename = file_path.split('/')[-1]
                self.filename_labels[index].setText(f"Gekozen bestand: '{filename}'")
                self.adjust_window_size()
                
        def adjust_window_size(self):
            self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())
            
        def get_scaled_logo(self):
            logo_image = Image.open(self.logo_path)
            logo_image.thumbnail((100, 100))
            logo_pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(ImageQt.ImageQt(logo_image))
            return logo_pixmap
    
        def set_excel_files(self, dfdata, dfeisen, sheetnamedata, sheetnameisen, filepathdata, filepatheisen):
            self.filepathdata = self.file_paths[0]
            self.filepatheisen = self.file_paths[1]
            self.sheetnamedata = pd.ExcelFile(self.file_paths[0]).sheet_names[0]
            self.sheetnameisen = 'EisenVoorXedule'
            dfdata = pd.read_excel(self.filepathdata, sheet_name=self.sheetnamedata, header=0)
            dfdata = dfdata.loc[~(dfdata == list(dfdata.columns)).all(axis=1)]
            dfeisen = pd.read_excel(self.filepatheisen, sheet_name=self.sheetnameisen, header=2, index_col=0)
    
        def run_data_loading_and_calculations(self):
            # print('ok')
            self.loader = DataLoader()
            self.loader.run_loading_and_calculations(int(45), self.dfdata, self.dfeisen, self.sheetnamedata, self.sheetnameisen, self.filepathdata, self.filepatheisen)

    class Evaluatiescherm(QWidget):
        def __init__(self, dataframes, headers, message):
            super().__init__()
            self.setWindowTitle("Evaluatie van data")
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    
            self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
            self.layout.addLayout(self.grid_layout)
            
            self.display_dataframes(dataframes, headers)
            self.add_message_label(message)
            self.add_save_button()
                
        def display_dataframes(self, dataframes, headers):
            self.dataframes = dataframes
            self.headers = headers
            row, col = 2, 0
    
            for df, header in zip(self.dataframes, self.headers):
                model = QStandardItemModel(self)
                table_view = QTableView(self)
    
                data = df.astype(str).values.tolist()
    
                model.setRowCount(len(df.index))
                model.setColumnCount(len(df.columns))
                model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)
    
                for r, row_data in enumerate(data):
                    for c, item in enumerate(row_data):
                        q_item = QStandardItem(item)
    
                        if c == len(df.columns) - 1:
                            value = float(item)
                            if value > 0:
                                q_item.setBackground(QColor("green"))
                            elif value < 0:
                                q_item.setBackground(QColor("red"))
    
                        model.setItem(r, c, q_item)
    
                table_view.setModel(model)
                table_view.setMinimumSize(table_view.sizeHint())
    
                self.grid_layout.addWidget(table_view, row + 1, col, alignment=Qt.Alignment())
    
                header_label = QLabel(header)
                self.grid_layout.addWidget(header_label, row, col, alignment=Qt.Alignment())
    
                col += 1
                if col > 1:
                    col = 0
                    row += 2
    
        def add_message_label(self, message):
            message_label = QLabel(message)
            message_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 14, QFont.Bold))
            message_label.setWordWrap(True)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(message_label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.Alignment())
    
        def add_save_button(self):
            save_button = QPushButton("Save as Excel")
            save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_excel)
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(save_button, self.grid_layout.rowCount(), 0, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.Alignment())
    
        def save_excel(self):
            default_filename = "Evaluatie_rooster.xlsx"
            save_path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save Excel File", default_filename, "Excel Files (*.xlsx)")
    
            if save_path:
                workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(save_path)
    
                for df, header in zip(self.dataframes, self.headers):
                    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(header)
    
                    for col, column in enumerate(df.columns):
                        worksheet.write(0, col + 1, column)
    
                    for row, index_value in enumerate(df.index):
                        worksheet.write(row + 1, 0, index_value)
    
                    for row, row_data in enumerate(df.itertuples(index=False), start=1):
                        for col, value in enumerate(row_data):
                            worksheet.write(row, col + 1, value)
    
                    last_column_letter = xlsxwriter.utility.xl_col_to_name(len(df.columns))
                    last_column_range = f"{last_column_letter}2:{last_column_letter}{len(df.index) + 1}"
    
                    if last_column_letter != "A":
                        positive_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'green'})
                        negative_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'red'})
    
                        worksheet.conditional_format(last_column_range, {'type': 'cell',
                                                                         'criteria': '>',
                                                                         'value': '0',
                                                                         'format': positive_format})
                        worksheet.conditional_format(last_column_range, {'type': 'cell',
                                                                         'criteria': '<',
                                                                         'value': '0',
                                                                         'format': negative_format})
    
                workbook.close()
                QMessageBox.information(self, "File Downloaded", "Bestand gedownload!")
            else:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Save Cancelled", "Opslaan geannuleerd!")
        
        def event(self, event):
            if event.type() == QEvent.WindowActivate:
                self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
                self.show()
            elif event.type() == QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
                self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
                self.hide()

            return super().event(event)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
        other_class = XeduleTool()
        
        if (loading_finishes == True) and (calculating_finishes == True):
            message = 'Generic message'
            headers = ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3']
            evaluatiescherm = Evaluatiescherm(dataframes_eval, headers, message)
            evaluatiescherm.show()
            
    
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

WHat was supposed to happen is that the unique values are returned but something goes wrong in transferring the excel to a pd dataframe.

I tried to fix it with making variables global or moving the function outside of the class but nothing seems to work.